# REST resource returning different object depending on state

Tags: json, rest

I'm trying to define a REST API and I'm having trouble with one requirement.
I have an action that the API user can do that is the same thing, but can be done in two different ways.

For example, say my user uses my API to change the intensity of a light. I will have an URL something like

api/light/intensity

One option the user has to change the intensity is to set as a % of the maximum luminosity, the other option is setting the intensity as an exact value, in lumens (there is a detector for that) and he can pass the "precision" that can be low, medium and high (it changes the time it takes to get to the correct intensity).

I want the user to be able to GET the current intensity, meaning in which mode he is and depending on the mode, the % or the value in lumens and the precision.

This is where I'm lost, my GET will return a JSON object for example, is it OK to send something like

```
{
   "Mode" = "Percent",
   "Percent" = 50.5
}
```

when I'm in "percentage" mode and

```
{
   "Mode" = "Exact",
   "Lumens" = 200,
   "Precision" = "High"
}
```

When I'm in "lumens" mode?

If that seems OK, how would I tell the user which type of "object" he should parse?

What would be the best way to let the user send his changes? I was thinking about having two URL, one for each mode, like
PUT /api/light/intensity/exact and PUT /api/light/intensity/percent

And both being waiting for JSON objects similar to the ones above, without the Mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [HTTP Content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). This allows:

- the client to tell the server what representation of a resource it wants to `GET`,
- the server to tell the client what representation of a resource it returns to the client,
- the client to tell the server what represenation of a resource it is `PUT`ing to the server.

Define two vendor content types:

- `application/vnd.com.example.light.intensity.percentage+json`
- `application/vnd.com.example.light.intensity.lumens+json`

The client tells the server which of both it wants:

```
GET /api/light/intensity/
Accept: application/vnd.com.example.light.intensity+percentage
```

The server responds:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.example.light.intensity+percentage

{
   "Percent" = 50.5
}
```

The client wants to change the intensity:

```
PUT /api/light/intensity/
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.example.light.intensity+percentage

{
   "Percent" = 42.7
}
```

The server knows  from the `Content-Type` header how to interpret the JSON body. In this example it handles the request as in 'Percent' mode.

If the second content type was used, client and server would know to interpret the request/response as in 'Lumes' mode.

**Edit:** Note that the `GET` and  `PUT` request use the *same* URL because the requests are about the same resource: the light intensity. All that differs is the *representation* of this resource. The proper way to handle this are content types.

Comment: In my case, on the "GET", the client shouldn't really be able to specify the representation. The representation will be depending on how the "light" has been set, in which mode it currently is.

But I guess that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

The specifics will depend a bit on your API, and the needs of your users. The same GET method call to a RESTful API should always return the same value: a representation of the resource as defined by the information in the URL and nothing else. <strike>If you're maintaining state in the system, you're violating a precept of REST.</strike> (**Edit**: as pointed out by Gimly, that statement is unclear. It's not a violation of RESTful design for the system to maintain its own internal state, especially if a request changes the state of the system with a `PUT`, `POST` or `DELETE`. It's a violation for a request to rely on that state to return a representation of the resource, or to request a state change. Each request should be self-contained.)

I'd use a query string to change the format of the representation:

```
GET /api/light/intensity
GET /api/light/intensity?f=percent
```

That way `/api/light/intensity` always refers to the same resource (defaulting to the "exact" representation, which has the most data), and the query string "filters" the representation, similarly to a search query. It removes some data (in this case, the exact luminosity and precision) in favor of a relative representation in percent of some maximum value. Alternately, you could think of it as controlling the output format: `GET /foo.json` vs `GET /foo.xml`. The resource is the same, but the representation differs.

For updating a resource, you can take an object as you've described. Your server will have to understand the different formats, but you could either `PUT` to the bare URL, or again use a query parameter to control the format expected by the server, and then let your payload be more abstract, using `value` instead of `lumens` or `percentage`:

```
PUT /api/light/intensity
  Payload: {"value": 200, "precision": "high"}

PUT /api/light/intensity?f=percent
  Payload: {"value": 50.5}
```

That allows you to structure the API for your `light` resource in such a way that `intensity` is one property of the resource. "Percent" then becomes a convenience representation in the output, so when you return the entire `light` resource, it would read something like:

```
"light": {
  "name": "the light",
  "id": 12345,
  "intensity": 200,
  "max-intensity": 400,
...
}
```

So the API user could calculate current percent based on `intensity` and `max-intensity`. (You could of course substitute "percent" for "max-intensity" and let the user do the math the other way, but it feels more natural to me to provide absolute values and let the math calculate relative values.

**Edit**

Please see Tichodroma's answer for the better way of handling this. I'm leaving the answer because the discussion in the comments was useful to me, and may be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Your approach is using differen URLs for the *same* resource which ist the light intensity. That is not RESTful. One resource, one URL.

Comment: Unless I'm missing a typo, the URLs are the same: `/api/light/intensity`. The representation changes from default ("exact", in OP's terms) to relative (or "percent") based on a query string. Different filters and formats can be controlled by query parameters without violating the canonical address of the resource itself. Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: `?f=percent` is part of the URL.

Comment: Query string parameters are commonly used to overcome user-agent limitations of not being able to easily specify content types. Yes, it is part of the URL, but common use cases allow for query string parameters to substitute for deeper parts of the request that cannot easily be modified by, say, a user browsing the web. In the same way, `/foo.xml` and `/foo.json` refer to the same `foo` resource, but request a different representation format, although it would be better to use content negotiation to do so.

Comment: Since the question mentions `PUT` we can assume that the client is a programmable client that can set headers and use content negotiation. A RESTful server for such a client must follow the rule: one resource, one URL.

Comment: I'm surprised by your remark about not maintaining a state on the system. REST's stateless requirement doesn't mean that the server cannot maintain a state about itself, it means that the server shouldn't maintain a context about the client who makes queries. Each request containing all information necessary for the server to service the request. If the server wouldn't be able to maintain a state of itself, there wouldn't be any use of PUT/POST/DELETE methods.

Comment: You're right, that's an unclear statement. I'll edit.